# Weird condition_variable::wait_for behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to use `wait_for` function of `std::condition_variable` compiled with Visual C++ 2017 however it returns random unexpected results with the following simple code (which never signals the variable, so it's supposed to always return timeout):

```
condition_variable m_cv;
mutex m_mutex;

void ThreadProc()
{
   while (1)
   {
      unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_mutex);
      cv_status r = m_cv.wait_for(lk, chrono::milliseconds(200));

      printf("Result %s\n", r == cv_status::timeout ? "timeout" : "no timeout");

      Sleep(100);
   }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   thread th(ThreadProc);
   th.join();

   return 0;
}
```

The results are random like:

```
Result no timeout
Result timeout
Result no timeout
Result timeout
Result timeout
Result timeout
Result timeout
Result no timeout
```

Am I doing something wrong or this is a compiler bug?

Comment: _"...It may also be unblocked spuriously...."_ see note to (1), try using (2) from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for

Comment: Hmm, that seems ridiculous, then what's the point of this function? :)

Comment: The point of the function is to wait for a condition to become true. You use it inside a loop that repeats the wait until the condition is true. That guards against spurious wake-ups.

Comment: The point is to make sure it never waits longer than `200` milliseconds. Use `wait_until` if you want accurate regular wake-up times (still checking for spurious events).

Comment: I see thanks, but why isn't that check done within wait function? Why would anyone need spurious return??

Comment: Hardware implementation of condition variables is more efficient when spurious wakeups are allowed (something to do with cache lines IIRC, but I don't really understand the machinery). And since a typical program has to deal with spurious wakeups anyway, there's no reason to disallow them. (continued)

Comment: Now - why does a typical program have to deal with spurious wakeup? Imagine two threads waiting on the same condition variable for, say, a unit of work to arrive on a queue. Another thread adds to the queue, and calls `notify_all`. Both threads wake up. One of them happens to be the first to grab the lock, and removes the element from the queue. Then the other one grabs the lock, and discovers that the queue is empty. From the point of view of this last thread, it has just experienced a spurious wakeup - it has awoken, only to discover that the condition it was waiting for was false.